# How to put vbs code to click on 2 buttons to make Chrome the default browser and associate with .htm

Tags: vbscript

I found below code in internet that enables win10 startup to run a file associate Chrome with .htm and .html... Purpose is to make Chrome the default web browser as somehow the win10 restore the default browser to IE on every single start up, which is annoying.

The vbs code only works to open Win10 file association list for manual choices, which every time it needs to be done as follows.

1. Check the "Select All" Check Box
2. Uncheck the ".pdf" as Adobe Reader is better than Chrome.
3. Click on "Save" button to close.

Current code:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "%windir%\system32\control.exe /name Microsoft.DefaultPrograms /page pageDefaultProgram\pageAdvancedSettings?pszAppName=google%20chrome"
WScript.Sleep 1200
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys " "
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WshShell.SendKeys " "
WScript.Quit
```

[The screen shot: https://ibb.co/3cQDR81][enter link description here][1](https://ibb.co/3cQDR81)
-----------Thank you very much!

I would like to make Chrome the default web browser as it restore to IE on every computer starts

if additional code can help automation of the 3 clicks, that will be wonderful.

Comment: Your question is confusing. Your title mentions the *default browser and associate with .htm*, but the text refers to *.pdf as Acrobat Reader is better than Chrome*. Also, if a user makes the association change, they don't reset when the machine is rebooted.  I know this for certain, because I set up computers on a corporate network regularly and part of setting up a profile for new users after they log in is setting the associations for Chrome and Acrobat Reader instead of Edge along with configuring default printers and taskbar icons for in-house apps.

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for your comment and sorry for confusion. The code is actually do one thing which is to open filed association. Every time when this file association windows opens, the .htm and web extensions as well as .pdf is not selected. I think the easiest way, by using mouse to click, is to "Select All" first and unselect .pdf as I would like Adobe Reader to continue associated with .pdf, not Chrome. Purpose is to associate Chrome with all web extensions such as .htm and not affecting other file association that Chrome wants to associate. if this one more clear, or not code logic? Thanks.